# Store compile time types for runtime use

Tags: c++, templates

I have a compile-time tuple like this:

```
using Tuple = std::tuple<std::array<double, 1>, std::array<double, 2>, std::array<double, 3>...>; // etc..
```

I wonder if there is a way to transform this tuple to a map, or vector, or any type of container(maybe some type of constructed container, i.e. not std container), which will contain these std::array-types(up to 1000 array-types of sizes 1 to 1000), and it will be possible to access these types at runtime?

It should preferably work with C++14, but C++ 17 and boost are fine as well.

**EDIT**: By accessing during runtime, I mean that it should be possible to use these types as type specifier when creating new objects, example:

```
    // Generate a container with all the types at compile time:
    auto container_with_types = {make_multi_array<double>(std::make_index_sequence<1000>{})}
    // At runtime:
    decltype(container_with_types(10)/*return std::array of size 10*/) standard_array;
```

Comment: There's `type_info`, but the problem with this question is that "access these types at runtime" is rather vague. Fundamentally, C++ is a compiled language.

Comment: All types are determined at compile-time. But since all those types are arrays with the same element type, do you really need to change the types at runtime? Maybe use `std::vector<double>`?

Comment: Could you post a snippet explaining what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @paolo Posted an example in my question now.

Comment: You cannot specify a type at runtime. Also, types are not values, so it is impossible to store them. "Array whose size is determined at runtime" is called `std::vector`.